Reply on the same Slack Thread using Azure Custom QuestionAnswering
I would kindly ask you to help on this topic if possible.
My Azure Bot based on Custom Question Answering is actually up and running:
based on the knowledge fixed question I get the corresponding answer.
This is the actual code I'm using within the qnaBotWithMSI.js file:
const { ActivityHandler } = require('botbuilder');
class QnABotWithMSI extends ActivityHandler {
    /**
     *
     * @param {ConversationState} conversationState
     * @param {UserState} userState
     * @param {Dialog} dialog
     */
    constructor(conversationState, userState, dialog) {
        super();
        if (!conversationState) throw new Error('[QnABotWithMSI]: Missing parameter. conversationState is required');
        if (!userState) throw new Error('[QnABotWithMSI]: Missing parameter. userState is required');
        if (!dialog) throw new Error('[QnABotWithMSI]: Missing parameter. dialog is required');

        this.conversationState = conversationState;
        this.userState = userState;
        this.dialog = dialog;
        this.dialogState = this.conversationState.createProperty('DialogState');

        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            console.log('Running dialog with Message Activity.');

            // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
            await this.dialog.run(context, this.dialogState);

            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
        // If a new user is added to the conversation:
        this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;
            for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; cnt++) {
                if (membersAdded[cnt].id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
                    const defaultWelcome = process.env.DefaultWelcomeMessage;
                    if (defaultWelcome !== '') await context.sendActivity(defaultWelcome);
                    else await context.sendActivity('Welcome to the QnA Maker');
                }
            }
            await next();
        });
    }
    async run(context) {
        await super.run(context);
        // Save any state changes. The load happened during the execution of the Dialog.
        await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context, false);
        await this.userState.saveChanges(context, false);
    }
}


The main goal would be to ask the question on Slack and have the bot replying. For that there's a Channel integration available via Azure Bot.
However the answer is provided not on the same corresponding message Thread, but as a new message published on the same Channel used for the integration, where the question has been asked.
If this is possible, may you kindly suggest how to edit the code, in order to get the answer on the same "question thread", rather than having a new message popping up in the channel?
Thank you in advance for your help :)
All details provided above, I'm actually not finding a proper solution for this

refer to link to Create a FAQ bot

To ensure your Azure Bot replies in the same Slack thread where the question was asked, you need to modify your bot code to include the replyToId property in the outgoing activity:
this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
    console.log('Running dialog with Message Activity.');
    await this.dialog.run(context, this.dialogState);
    if (context.activity.conversation && context.activity.conversation.id) {
        const threadId = context.activity.conversation.id; 
        context.activity.replyToId = threadId; 
    }
    await next();
});


Set the replyToId to ensure the response is sent as part of the Slack thread:
const response = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(context);

if (response.length > 0) {
    const replyText = response[0].answer;
    const replyActivity = {
        type: ActivityTypes.Message,
        text: replyText,
        replyToId: context.activity.id 
    };
    await context.sendActivity(replyActivity);
} else {
    await context.sendActivity({
        type: ActivityTypes.Message,
        text: 'No answers were found.',
        replyToId: context.activity.id 
    });
}




I referred to this link for guidance on using Azure Custom Question Answering to answer questions in a bot service.
Below code to create a bot that can answer questions using content from an FAQ.
The bot uses below Azure Cognitive Services Custom Question Answering service:
const path = require('path');

const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: ENV_FILE });

const restify = require('restify');

const {
    ActivityTypes,
    CloudAdapter,
    ConfigurationBotFrameworkAuthentication
} = require('botbuilder');

const { CustomQABot } = require('./bots/CustomQABot');

const botFrameworkAuthentication = new ConfigurationBotFrameworkAuthentication(process.env);

const adapter = new CloudAdapter(botFrameworkAuthentication);

adapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
    const traceActivity = {
        type: ActivityTypes.Trace,
        timestamp: new Date(),
        name: 'onTurnError Trace',
        label: 'TurnError',
        value: `${ error }`,
        valueType: 'https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error'
    };
  
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError] unhandled error: ${ error }`);
    await context.sendActivity(traceActivity);

   
    await context.sendActivity('The bot encountered an error or bug.');
    await context.sendActivity('To continue ');
};

const bot = new CustomQABot();

const server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());

server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function() {
    console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }`);
    console.log('\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator');
});

server.post('/api/messages', async (req, res) => {
    
    await adapter.process(req, res, (context) => bot.run(context));
});


Output:



Hello Sampath, unfortunately when I try to add the second portion of the code, O get some issues, setting: const response = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(context);  checking documentation it seems “starting 1st October, 2022 you won’t be able to create new qna maker resources

If you have any code working for this use case, it would be definitely very nice to know about
